# Deciding if it is more appropriate to use tree models rather than logistic model s

Tags: r, regression, logistic, classification, cart

Consider this scenario, if I have a predictor,  gender, and another predictor, age, and I know that age only matters when the subject is a Male and age makes no difference when the gender is Female, should I use a tree model in place of logistic models?

If I use a logistic model, would the correlation between age and gender cause some kind of bias?

what is the best kind  of model to use for this scenario?

Comment: "best" depends on a lot of things you haven't specified ... to the extent that this may be too broad/ opinion based. *An* alternative (and a very common one!) is to consider interaction between age and gender.

Answer (score 1):

You may well find a way to build a productive model using a tree-type method, such as a Classification and Regression Tree (CART) or Chi-square-Based Automatic Interaction Detection (CHAID).  Logistic regression may be just as successful.  The important thing to grasp first is the difference between two types of relationships.

First, there is what you've termed "**correlation**."  (In this case, a more correct term would be "association," since strictly speaking a categorical variable like gender can not be said to correlate.)  Two variables are associated when a certain level or category of one tends to coincide with a certain level or category of the other.  That isn''t actually the best way to describe your situation.

What you have is a case of "**interaction**."  Interaction is more complex:  the way variable A relates to variable B differs depending on the level or category of variable C.  From your description, age relates to your outcome differently depending on whether the subject is male (there's a connection) or female (there isn't).  You might say there are "different slopes for different folks."

Technical accounts of the difference between association and interaction abound.  If you'd like to read a somewhat detailed, non-technical one, you could try [mine](http://www.integrativestatistics.com/partial.htm).

Tree-based methods such as CART and CHAID may uncover interactions for you.  Using logistic regression you could program in your own, so in that way you would include it in your model rather than having an unaccounted-for dynamic distort your findings.  Thus you would avoid building what is called a "misspecified" model.